# Flutter audio_service ?? android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, android-developer-api, flutter-plugin

In Flutter I am using audio_service(Android/IOS) plugin to play audio in the background .

When I click pause , play or any button in notification shown in background, the Service throws the following error.
What's wrong with this?

**pubspec.yaml file include :**

```
audio_session: ^0.0.10 
just_audio: ^0.6.9 
audio_service: ^0.16.2    
rxdart: ^0.24.1
```

========================================================================

I add the following tags in my androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

then in my class I call my player class with this instruction

```
 Container(
        child: AudioServiceWidget(child:Player()),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      )
```

my player class contains the same code listed here but ,the difference it's inside my tree widgets not in the main like in the example below :
https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service/example

```
import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
    import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
    import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
    
    class Player extends StatelessWidget  {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
    child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
    stream: AudioService.runningStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                           ...........................
                           .............................
    } } }
```

now when I use my app the player work but when i click on buttons upside the notification bar the app crashes and gives me the following errors.

**ADB Log :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.flutter_app1, PID: 10992
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1793)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:451)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

**ADB LOG After put AndroidServiceWidget directly in my class. the player works perfectly but the app crashes after clicked a button from player notification Bar :**

```
021-02-18 16:01:12.980 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 D/MediaBrowserCompat: Connecting to a MediaBrowserService.
2021-02-18 16:01:13.024 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 W/MediaButtonReceiver: More than one BroadcastReceiver that handles android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON was found, returning null.
2021-02-18 16:01:13.024 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 W/MediaSessionCompat: Couldn't find a unique registered media button receiver in the given context.
2021-02-18 16:01:20.249 28652-28659/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=111KB
2021-02-18 16:01:20.259 28652-28659/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=101KB, data=70KB
2021-02-18 16:01:20.313 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init 7e1bce [ExoPlayerLib/2.12.2] [TECNO-KA7-GO, TECNO KA7, TECNO MOBILE LIMITED, 27]
2021-02-18 16:01:20.604 28652-28829/com.example.flutter_app1 I/System.out: isEmailSend:GET
2021-02-18 16:01:20.706 28652-28668/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 79822(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 43(1144KB) LOS objects, 79% free, 2MB/11MB, paused 503us total 185.099ms
2021-02-18 16:01:20.799 28652-28829/com.example.flutter_app1 I/System.out: port:443
2021-02-18 16:01:20.876 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 W/le.flutter_app1: type=1400 audit(0.0:8059): avc: denied { search } for name="clients" dev="debugfs" ino=7420 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs_ion:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-02-18 16:01:20.879 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels + 
2021-02-18 16:01:21.071 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 D/skia: SkJpegCodec::onGetPixels -
2021-02-18 16:01:21.521 28652-28668/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 4664(306KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 79% free, 2MB/11MB, paused 214us total 177.472ms
2021-02-18 16:01:21.787 28652-28829/com.example.flutter_app1 I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
2021-02-18 16:01:21.789 28652-28829/com.example.flutter_app1 I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2021-02-18 16:01:22.290 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-adpcm-ms
2021-02-18 16:01:22.292 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-adpcm-dvi-ima
2021-02-18 16:01:22.295 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/alac
2021-02-18 16:01:22.303 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ape
2021-02-18 16:01:22.382 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
2021-02-18 16:01:22.421 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 1/32 for video/mp4v-es
2021-02-18 16:01:22.421 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
2021-02-18 16:01:22.421 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/64 for video/mp4v-es
2021-02-18 16:01:22.436 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/flv1
2021-02-18 16:01:22.475 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
2021-02-18 16:01:22.482 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/xvid
2021-02-18 16:01:22.520 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 1/32 for video/mp4v-es
2021-02-18 16:01:22.527 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2021-02-18 16:01:22.859 28652-28834/com.example.flutter_app1 I/OMXClient: Treble IOmx obtained
2021-02-18 16:01:22.899 28652-28834/com.example.flutter_app1 I/ACodec: codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
2021-02-18 16:01:23.011 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 3675 for frameCount 11025
2021-02-18 16:01:23.242 28652-28659/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=99KB
2021-02-18 16:01:23.278 28652-28659/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=99KB
2021-02-18 16:01:23.278 28652-28659/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2021-02-18 16:01:29.662 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 69361597167560 < limitNs: 69367023999339 < mStartNs: 69367075999339
2021-02-18 16:01:29.681 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 69361597167560 < limitNs: 69367023999339 < mStartNs: 69367075999339
2021-02-18 16:01:29.691 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 69361597167560 < limitNs: 69367023999339 < mStartNs: 69367075999339
2021-02-18 16:01:29.701 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 69361597167560 < limitNs: 69367023999339 < mStartNs: 69367075999339
2021-02-18 16:01:29.711 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 I/chatty: uid=10467(com.example.flutter_app1) ExoPlayer:Playb identical 1 line
2021-02-18 16:01:29.721 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 69361597167560 < limitNs: 69367023999339 < mStartNs: 69367075999339
2021-02-18 16:01:29.732 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 69361597167560 < limitNs: 69367023999339 < mStartNs: 69367075999339
2021-02-18 16:01:29.742 28652-28828/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 69361597167560 < limitNs: 69367023999339 < mStartNs: 69367075999339
2021-02-18 16:01:36.585 28652-28668/com.example.flutter_app1 I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 29851(1403KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(324KB) LOS objects, 70% free, 3MB/12MB, paused 596us total 101.321ms
2021-02-18 16:01:55.133 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-02-18 16:01:55.152 28652-28652/com.example.flutter_app1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.flutter_app1, PID: 28652
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1793)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:451)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Comment: I can't tell alone just from that part of the log. But if you use `adb logcat` you might see other reasons logged leading up to that point. For example, it may be that you haven't added all of the required things to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. For example, the permissions and the receiver and service components.

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                                                                             
 About AndroidManifest.xml, I follow the steps included in this link https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service (Android Section).  I want to add that, when I create new project and I include audio_service plugin  it works perfectly but when I include it to my project it doesn"t.

Comment: Still, I can't tell alone just from that part of the log, so it would be helpful to update your question with any other details that would help someone to answer, including relevant pieces of code and configuration (e.g. start options)

Comment: Thank's another time. I add more clarifications about my issue please check it .

Comment: Still not enough information for me to tell, sorry. The only thing wrong I can see is that you did not insert the AudioServiceWidget the top of the widget tree for the `/` route. However, I suspect there is also another error, preceding this which is why I asked you to check adb logcat (and also the `start()` options) . Probably the earlier happened when starting audio service so you'll need to look into that and gather more information.

Comment: so , I insert the AudioServiceWidget in my route widget , in my case it's splashScreen like this  --->  home: AudioServiceWidget(child:SplashScreen())                                         [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Not connected
E/flutter (23248): #0      AudioService.start.<anonymous closure> (package:audio_service/audio_service.dart:804:24)
E/flutter (23248): #1      _AsyncTaskQueue._process (package:audio_service/audio_service.dart:2007:45)

Comment: I add full log after I click the button in player notification bar.